# Retrieve records falling within a daily time range across a given month

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table contains fields that store

- ticket
- sale date/time
- price

I need help on how to select only those tickets sold between 8:00 AM and 12:00 PM on a day-to-day basis for an entire month, *without* including any sales between 12:01 PM and 10:00 PM.

Comment: Can you show what you have done?

Comment: for a day its easy to get, by  select sum (price) from mytable where sale_date between  1/1/2015 8:00 am and 1/1/2015 12:00 PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to deal with events in given hours of day is to use DATEPART

```
SELECT *
FROM TicketTable
WHERE DATEPART(hh, SaleDateTime) BETWEEN 8 AND 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
SELECT SUM(Price) Total_Morning_Sales
FROM TableName 
WHERE CAST(Sale AS TIME) > '07:59:59'
 AND  CAST(Sale AS TIME) < '12:00:01'
 AND  MONTH(Sale) = 5   --<-- Month Number here
```